# How does UIActionSheet showInView method insert its view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, customization, uiactionsheet

Im trying to implement my own CustomUIActionSheet.

I have it almost working, but I have no idea how does the showInView method works.

- (void)showInView:(UIView *)view

giving a view, this method is capable of put its view in front of every single view (adding it to the windows maybe?) but its also capable of settings the rotation accordingly to the view in which is being added.

Ive tried adding it to the windows of the view that I recieve as a parameter.

```
CGFloat startPosition = view.window.bounds.origin.y + view.window.bounds.size.height;

self.frame = CGRectMake(0, startPosition, view.window.bounds.size.width, [self calculateSheetHeight]);

[view.window addSubview:self];

self.blackOutView = [self buildBlackOutViewWithFrame:view.window.bounds];
[view.window insertSubview:self.blackOutView belowSubview:self];
```

By doing this, all works, except that when I present the action sheet in landscape, the action sheet apears from the right (since the windows system reference its always the same)

I´ve also tried to add it to the rootViewController of the view windows like that:

```
UIView * view = view.window.rootViewController.view;

 CGFloat startPosition = view.bounds.origin.y + view.bounds.size.height;

 self.frame = CGRectMake(0, startPosition, view.bounds.size.width, [self calculateSheetHeight]);

 [view addSubview:self];

 self.blackOutView = [self buildBlackOutViewWithFrame:view.bounds];
 [view insertSubview:self.blackOutView belowSubview:self];
```

but again, it fails in landscape, it doesnt add anything or at least, I can not see it

So, my question is, any clue of how can I add a view to the top of the hierarchy working in both orientations?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some source code of custom alert views and other ui components that are dranw in the top of the hierarchy I found a working solution.

Adding the view in the first subview of the windows:

```
UIView * topView = [[view.window subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

So the final code is

```
UIView * topView = [[view.window subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

CGFloat startPosition = topView.bounds.origin.y + topView.bounds.size.height;

self.frame = CGRectMake(0, startPosition, topView.bounds.size.width, [self calculateSheetHeight]);

[topView addSubview:self];

self.blackOutView = [self buildBlackOutViewWithFrame:topView.bounds];
[topView insertSubview:self.blackOutView belowSubview:self];
```